# My Keyboard won't toggle: neither endEditing nor resignFirstResponder works

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I'm using Text Field, and the view that text field is on is made by 
`UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nickNameInput") as! PopupViewController` .

It's a PopupViewController.

The problem is that when I call 
`textField.resignFirstResponder()`or  `self.view.endEditing(true)` , neither of them works...

I'm having a hard time. Can someone please help me?

```
    import UIKit

    class PopupViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var editingEndBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var inputString = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        view.insertSubview(blurView, at: 0)

        textField.delegate = self
        editingEndBtn.isEnabled = false
    }



    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {    //delegate method
    }

    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {  //delegate method
        inputString = textField.text!
        //print(inputString)
        if (inputString != ""){
            editingEndBtn.isEnabled = true
        }

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
         self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
       textField.resignFirstResponder()
        print("return is pushed")
        toggleKeyboard()
        return true
    }


}
```

Comment: you should never ever name any outlet similar to apple inbuilt declared variables, this can cause issues. For e.g :- you named your textfield like "textField" and you can see in textfield delegate methods there is parameter named textField is already there. so avoid using such name conventions. this may be helpful to you https://www.mobomo.com/2017/03/naming-conventions-for-swift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   
    return false // this prevents it
}
```

You need to remove this method or handle it logically according to text without returning `false` anyway like

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    inputString = textField.text! 
    return  inputString != ""
}
```